# Call static method in PHP across variable

Tags: php, laravel, static-methods

I working in Laravel project and I can't call static method across variable
For example:

```
$objName = 'User';
$objName::get();
```

On this way I get error.

Comment: 'user' is a string, not an object

Comment: @noid, in php you can call Class with string variable

Comment: `I get error.` which is?

Comment: You are correct, i need more coffee...

Answer (score 1):

```
$objName = 'User';
```

Is a string, for using the `get()` method $objName should be an object, for example:

```
$objName = User::all()->first(); // this will return an object
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I use

```
User::all();
```

But I want get parametar from URL for example www.example.com/User, www.example.com/Articles -> User and Article is parametar in URL (this is Laravel web route) and call static method. When I wrtie first URL than call User object if I write first URL than call Article object.

www.example.com/User

```
$param= 'User';
$param::all();
```

www.example.com/Article

```
$param= 'Article';
$param::all()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution!
This solution in Laravel:

```
$data = call_user_func( array('\App\\'.$param , 'all'));
```

but if you want use in plain PHP then is:

```
$data = call_user_func( array($param , 'all'));
```

This will call Object and Method.

If you want to send arg in methond thent is:

```
$data = call_user_func( array('\App\\'.$param , 'all'), $arg);  /*For Laravel*/
$data = call_user_func( array($param , 'all'), $arg);  /*For plain PHP*/
```